# Why faces messages on a component is additive?

Tags: jsf

I am adding validation messages to my component. I have a number of inputs and then I am validating them together in a validator attached to hidden input which is declared above all these components. I am seeing that everytime the validation fails , the *same* messages keep on getting added.

A message like " *input x greater than input Y*" shows up twice even though it should show up once. Then I correct the error values and it is gone . Next I deliberately insert the same error values again . Then I will see the above error message *three* times .

How can I clear messages from previous request?

Here's the contrived relevant code:

```
if (all condition passes) {
    for(UIInput:components){
        input.setValid(true);
    }


} else {
      //Find out the first component that fails the validation and mark it red
      FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
      UIInput input= components.getInvalidComponent();
      input.setValid(false);
      context.addMessage(input.getClientId(context),message) ;                           
    }
```

**P.S: I am using JSF1.2**

Comment: Faces messages are request scoped. So your *"messages from previous request"* has no valid grounds. The duplicate message is really been added within the very same request. Just put a debug breakpoint on `FacesContext#addMessage()` to naildown the culprit. Or, perhaps, you're using ajax and was being mislead by rendering inconsitenties.

Comment: @BalusC Yes I am using ajax but I didn't understand your point about rendering inconsistency.Can you please explain what you meant?

Comment: For example, the previous messages have not been cleared from the HTML DOM during rendering of the ajax response. Hard to tell by lack of information about the ajax library used and seeing the HTTP response body of the ajax request.

Comment: @BalusC other than this am I doing anything fundamentally wrong here?